# Jquery ajax call a php script with require once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "services/Test.class.php",
    data: "call=getTest",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Error getting php file");
    }
});
```

So, in my class ( Test.class.php ), I have a `getTest()` function and a `require_once('OtherPHP')`,

When I test this code, I have an error in require once :

**No such file or directory**

in my `alert(data)`
how can I fix it?

Comment: No, my error is in the Test.class.php, so i think i have the good path

Comment: wher is the otherPHP file located?

Comment: @Felix was referring to the location (path) of that _other_ required file. Just have a try calling "services/Test.class.php" directly with a browser.

Comment: I'm using Test.class.php with an other way and it's ok, so i don't think i have a problem with my path :)

Comment: Can you post the relevant PHP code as well?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've included a wrong path of `OtherPHP` file in Test.class.php. Use `file_exists()` function to make sure that given path really exists before including/requiring in `Test.class.php`

```
if (file_exists(`OtherPHP.php`)) {
    require_once(`OtherPHP.php`)
} else {
    echo "The file `OtherPHP.php` does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to call the class directly from ajax,

- create new php file say test.php

in test.php

```
   include("Test.class.php");    
   $test = new Test();
   $test ->getTest(); //print the getTest outpout here
```

Javascript:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",

        .....
```